# Prove that a sequilinear form is an Hermitian product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

I cannot start the following exercise. Let $V$ be a complex vector space such that $\operatorname{dim}V=n$ and $B=(\underline{e}_1,\ldots,\underline e_n)$ a basis for $V$. Let also $g:V\times V\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ a sesquilinear map with associated matrix $G$ with respect to $B$ of the form
$$
G=\overline{A}^TA
$$
for an invertible matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}_{n\times n}$. Prove that $g$ is an Hermitian scalar product.

Some ideas?

Thank You

Comment: You have to check the definition. Compute $g(v,w)$ first, by decomposing $v,w$ in coordinates with respect to $B$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro How can I compute $g(v, w)$?

Comment: Look up in your book for the definition of "sesquilinear map with associated matrix with respect to $B$".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro For $\underline v=\sum_ib_i\underline e_i$ and $\underline w=\sum_ic_i\underline e_i$, we have that $g(v, w)=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)G(c_1,\ldots,c_n)^T$. Is it right?

Comment: Yes. Go on. Please, don't wait for corroboration at each step, try to get going alone before asking again.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro In order to prove that $g$ is an Hermitian scalar product, I have to prove that $G=\overline{G}^T$ (trivially verified) and that $\overline{\underline v}^TG\underline v\geq0$, for all $\underline v\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and it is $0$ iff $\underline v=\underline 0$. Now, it is $0$ iff $\underline v=\underline 0$ because $A$ is invertible (and then it cannot be null). How can I prove that $\overline{\underline v}^T\overline{A}^TA\underline v\geq0$?

Comment: Great. Notice that for each vector $h\in\mathbb C^n$, the term $\overline{h}^T h $ is a sum of squares.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Then can I conclude that $\overline{\underline v}^T\overline{A}^TA\underline v=\|A\underline v\|^2>0$ ?